# JDBC ResultSet object types mapping has no Byte or Short? Why Integer only?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, mapping, resultset

Good day. Can anyone explain why JDBC doesn't implement object mapping for some types. For example, Postgres JDBC has no Byte and Short mapping. I can get primitive byte and short, but in object format I can get only Integer.

This is source code from [here](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/246b759cdc264c2732717dbd6ff9f8f472024196/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgResultSet.java#L182)

```
case Types.TINYINT:
case Types.SMALLINT:
case Types.INTEGER:
    return getInt(columnIndex);
```

What's wrong wtih Byte and Short object types? How can I work with TINYINT, SMALLINT and so on.

What's problem to implement getByte and getShort similar to [getInt](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/blob/246b759cdc264c2732717dbd6ff9f8f472024196/pgjdbc/src/main/java/org/postgresql/jdbc/PgResultSet.java#L2065)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in the [JDBC™ 4.1 Specification JSR 221](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jdbc-4_1-mrel-eval-spec/jdbc4.1-fr-spec.pdf)
on page 187

> **Note** – The JDBC 1.0 specification defined the Java object mapping for
>   the SMALLINT and TINYINT JDBC types to be Integer. The Java language
>   did not include the Byte and Short data types when the JDBC 1.0
>   specification was finalized. The mapping of SMALLINT and TINYINT to
>   Integer is maintained to preserve backwards compatibility.

Comment: It's really sad. We are using 4.1 Specification now, but still keep backward compatibility with version 1.0. I don't care about compatibility. I tired to write ResultSet wrappers and sql util methods.

Answer (score 0):

Backward compatibility to JDBC Specification 1.0 don't let to add Byte and Short object types in JDBC drivers. There is only one solution: java crutch.

```
static public Integer getInteger(final ResultSet rs, final String columnName) throws SQLException {
    final int value = rs.getInt(columnName);
    return rs.wasNull() ? null : value;
}
```

Or

```
public <T> T getObjectValue(final ResultSet rs, final String columnName, final Class<T> clazz) throws SQLException {
    final T value = rs.getObject(columnName, clazz);
    return rs.wasNull() ? null : value;
}
```

And

```
public final class ResultSetWrapper {

    private final ResultSet rs;

    public ResultSetWrapper(final ResultSet rs) {
        this.rs = rs;
    }

    public ResultSet getResultSet() {
        return rs;
    }

    public Boolean getBoolean(String label) throws SQLException {
        // ...
    }

    public Byte getByte(String label) throws SQLException {
        // ...
    }

    public Byte getShort(String label) throws SQLException {
        // ...
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: You could just use `getObject(idx, Integer.class)` if you really want an object. No need to do this yourself.