# Mysql JDBC conversion between Short and Integer: not supported?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

MySql column type `smallint`, it is mapped to java type `java.lang.Integer`. Should it be `java.lang.Short`?

```
resultSet.getObject(index, Short.class)

java.sql.SQLException: Conversion not supported for type java.lang.Short
```

Why JDBC does not support such basic conversion?

Comment: It's not JDBC, it's the MySQL JDBC driver.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005762/jdbc-resultset-object-types-mapping-has-no-byte-or-short-why-integer-only?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDBC is only a set of interfaces and [requirements](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221), the behavior must be explicitly implemented in a driver (in your case, MySQL Connector/J). For [`getObject(int/String, Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-), the API specifies:

> Retrieves the value of the designated column in the current row of
>   this `ResultSet` object and will convert from the SQL type of the
>   column to the requested Java data type, if the conversion is
>   supported. If the conversion is not supported or null is specified for
>   the type, a `SQLException` is thrown.
>
> **At a minimum, an implementation must support the conversions defined
>   in Appendix B, Table B-3** and conversion of appropriate user defined
>   SQL types to a Java type which implements `SQLData`, or `Struct`.
>   Additional conversions may be supported and are vendor defined.

Table B-3 specifies the following conversion for `smallint`:

> `SMALLINT` | `Integer`

In other words, the behavior of the MySQL Connector/J driver complies with the JDBC specification, although MySQL would be allowed to support more extensive conversions for `getObject(String/int, Class)`.

As far as I'm aware, a lot of JDBC drivers do support more extensive conversions, and will also support the reverse of the mapping specified for `setObject` in table B-4:

> `Short` | `SMALLINT`

This mapping means that `setObject(int, <Short value>)` should set SQL type `SMALLINT` for the parameter (for databases/drivers that support dynamic (or need explicit) typing of the parameter value).

And, some also support the additional `setObject` conversions from B-5 for `getObject`:

> `Short` | `TINYINT, SMALLINT, INTEGER, BIGINT, REAL, FLOAT, DOUBLE, DECIMAL, NUMERIC, BIT, BOOLEAN, CHAR, VARCHAR, LONGVARCHAR`

The disconnect between `getObject` using `Integer` and `setObject` supporting `Short` (and others) is largely historical. Until JDBC 4.1 (Java 7), there was only one mapping for `getObject` (there was no `Class` parameter), and the initial version of JDBC mapped all integral types except `BIGINT` to `java.lang.Integer`. This is explicitly mentioned in the specification:

> Note – The JDBC 1.0 specification defined the Java object mapping for
>   the `SMALLINT` and `TINYINT` JDBC types to be `Integer`. The Java
>   language did not include the `Byte` and `Short` data types when the
>   JDBC 1.0 specification was finalized. The mapping of `SMALLINT` and
>   `TINYINT` to `Integer` is maintained to preserve backwards
>   compatibility.

So requiring `getObject(String/int, Class)` to at least support `java.lang.Integer` for `smallint` retains the backwards compatibility and the symmetry with `getObject(String/int)` returning a `java.lang.Integer` for a `smallint`. Not requiring (but allowing) the full set of conversions that are mandated for `setObject` makes the addition/transition easier for driver implementations.

Comment: Basically can not depend on JDBC doing conversion.

Comment: Is there a way to check if a conversion to a java type is supported?

Comment: @Sunnyday No, but in this case, if you really need a short why not just use `getShort`?

Comment: getShort(...) will convert any Number to short? Actually the java type is dynamic in our case.

Comment: @Sunnyday Yes, see table B-6 in the specification, however exact behavior can vary, some drivers will throw an exception if the value is out of range, others will register a warning and apply the same conversion you get when casting.

Comment: If getShort(...) can convert Integer to Short, why getObject(index, Short.class) can not convert Integer to Short? They should use the same conversion logic, right?

Comment: @Sunnyday Actually, no it isn't, and they don't. It may make it easier to add it, but it doesn't 'automatically' provide such functionality: the conversion will still need to be programmed explicitly in the driver, and since the JDBC specification doesn't require it, it looks like the MySQL developers didn't bother adding it.